# @RunAs annotation use on Servlet

Tags: java, security, servlets, ejb, runas

I have a simple question about @RunAs.

Besides an EJB, can I use @RunAs on a Servlet to propagate security role? for example as:

I have a public servlet:

```
@WebServlet(name = "RunAsServlet", urlPatterns = "/runAs")
@RunAs("Admin")
public class RunAsServlet extends HttpServlet {

@EJB
private MyEjb ejb;

@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
    resp.getWriter().write(ejb.doSomething());
    }
}
```

And the an EJB is protected under role "Admin":

```
@Stateless
@RolesAllowed("Admin")
public class MyEjb {

@Resource
private SessionContext sessionContext;

public String doSomething() {
```

In this case, I should be able to call the RunAsServlet since the @RunAs is on it, it shall have the proper role "Admin" to call the EJB protected method from web request, Am I right about this example? Or I need other more configuration?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You need to map specific user to the `roleOnServlet` role and this user must be also in `Admin` role. Either it is a typo or you have 2 different roles `roleOnServlet` != `Admin`.
Usually one use the same role name in servlet as in EJB that must be called. As in your case although servlet will be running as user in `roleOnServlet` role, he doesn't necessary have to be in the `Admin` role at the same time, which will lead to error.

`@RunAs` is not changing the current user to have that role, but is using separate user, which must be one of the users mapped to the `roleOnServlet` role.

Mapping of the user to runAs role is container specific, so if you need help in that, add information what server are you using.